# Spring exception but application starts

Tags: spring, jpa

To start my Spring application I just call

```
SpringApplication.run(TestclientApplication.class, args);
```

But because my application does not run stable and shuts down randomly, I put a try catch block around it. Like this..

```
    try {
        SpringApplication.run(TestclientApplication.class, args);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);

    }
```

Interestingly now I get an exception. I wonder why my application started before but of Course this exception was not caught before. But anyway. This is the exception.

```
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException

ERROR 20792 --- [           main] d.e.t.c.a.TestcaseController     : null
```

The funny Thing is I put a `@Profile("test")` above the Controller , so the Controller would only be loaded in case of test, but still I get this error.